# Implement a multithreat in gwt with http request

Tags: gwt

I need implement a system with multithreat in GWT.

What is the best way to do this???

I am using http request, json
and web service building in php

Thanks

Comment: Have you attempted something first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GWT code is translated to JavaScript which is not multithreaded (or at least, not in a way accessible to the user).

There are ways to program around tasks and callbacks in GWT. Take a look at the Scheduler class.